# Google TTS API - Selecting Different Google Voices using JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I have a chatGPT Powered chatbot I am building in JS with TTS support I have got it working using elevenLabs API without issue and managed to get googleTTS to sort of work but I am having a weird issue. I have radio buttons which allow the user to select a male or female voice, once selected the relevant request is sent to the API and the audio plays back the chatGPT response. What is happening though is that it is playing back a female voice regardless of which option is selected. I have been trying to debug it for a couple days and can't figure it out. Console logs are showing that the gender is set and that voice received back from Google should be the male voice (US Wavenet D) however its still playing a female voice!?

Here is the relevant code;

googleTTS.api

```
import { TextToSpeechClient } from "@google-cloud/text-to-speech";
import { config as loadEnvConfig } from "dotenv";

loadEnvConfig();

const client = new TextToSpeechClient({
keyFilename: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
});

export default async function (req, res) {
const { text, voice } = req.body;

console.log(`Received voice: ${voice}`);


const voiceName = voice === "male" ? "en-US-Wavenet-D" : "en-AU-Wavenet-C";
const languageCode = voice === "male" ? "en-US" : "en-AU";
const ssmlGender = voice === "male" ? "MALE" : "FEMALE";

const voiceConfig = {
name: voiceName,
languageCode: voiceName.slice(0, 5),
ssmlGender: voice === "male" ? "MALE" : "FEMALE",
};
console.log(`Received voiceConfig: ${JSON.stringify(voiceConfig)}`);

const audioConfig = {
audioEncoding: "MP3",
};

const request = {
input: { text },
voice: voiceConfig,
audioConfig,
};

try {
const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
const audioContent = response.audioContent;
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg");
res.send(Buffer.from(audioContent, "binary"));
} catch (error) {
console.error(`Error with Google TTS API request: ${error.message}`);
res.status(500).json({
error: {
message: "An error occurred during your request",
},
});
}
}
```

and this is code from my index.jsx;

```
setPromptInput("");

const ttsEndpoint = ttsProvider === "ElevenLabs" ? "/api/elevenLabs" : "/api/googleTTS";
const voiceParam = ttsProvider === "GoogleTTS" ? (voice === "female" ? "en-AU-Wavenet-C" : "en-US- 
Wavenet-D") : (voice === "female" ? "female" : "male");
console.log(`Selected voice: ${voice}`);
console.log(`Sending voice to TTS API: ${voiceParam}`);
```

sorry if this is a very specific question but hoping any JS gurus out there might be able to help.

The code is supposed to play back either a male or female voice depending which radio button is selected but it always plays back a female voice regardless which option is selected.